# loading PDFs into the android webview

Tags: android, pdf, webview

in my **android** application I have to load **PDFs** in the server into a **webview**. according to a stack-overflow question I used **Google DOC view** in loading it. but my problem is some times it does not show the file in the **webview** while in another instance it displays quite well. I can't figure out the problem. but the code appears to be OK. my code segment is as below.

```
WebViewLable.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
    WebViewLable.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    WebViewLable.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);  

    fullURL=GoogleDOCview+"https://livefarmer.com/labels/"+itemURL;
    WebViewLable.loadUrl(fullURL);

}

private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            WebView view, String url) {
        return(false);
    }
}
```

and my webview is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bg_black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        layout="@layout/nav_bar" />


    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webViewLable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the logcat output when it not showing the pdf.

[image]

this is the logcat output when it showing the pdf in the webview.

[image]

So whats the wrong with my code. how can I fix this.
Thanks and regards!

Comment: What is `WebViewLable`? Is this even real code? What is `GoogleDOCview`, and what is `itemURL`?

Comment: yep. this is a real code. from which I'm working on now. So I can't post whole code as it's not belongs to me. **WebViewLable** is my webview. the PDFs I'm loading are taking from a server. and **itemURL** is the URL of those and **GoogleDOCview** is Google Document Viewer.

Comment: there no any change in  Logcat while pdf is showing or not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String PdfUrl = "http://pdfexample.com/abcd.pdf";
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + PdfUrl;
Log.i(TAG, "PDF URL : " + url);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

try this

Comment: some times it display, some times it doesn't.

Comment: no it always display it,, please try this code only dear

Comment: no dear. it's not always working. those PDFs contains only two to three pages. and it still works the same.

Comment: do you have any idea on this problem.... ????? some times it loads PDFs properly. but I couldn't track the error. it shows no error messages in log-cat.

Comment: after taking some time big pdf is load or not ?

Comment: no dear. in my case I have to use small PDFs, in most cases contains only two to three pages. so it's appears to be that's not the problem. and I added the logcats in two instances. :)

Comment: please remove   WebViewLable.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    WebViewLable.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60070/discussion-between-vaishali-and-samantha-withanage).

Comment: did it. but same outcome.

Comment: you got issue still ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953604/reading-pdf-from-url-using-pdfviewer-library-in-android-app/14954196#14954196 see this

Comment: Hi guys! This thread is quite old, but I'm facing the same problem: sometimes the pdf is not displayed into the webview (and it seems a pretty random behavior) .. did you manage to find a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, if any one still facing same problem try below solution which working fine https://stackoverflow.com/a/63900835/8265484

Answer (score 0):

The way I have managed to resolve the above is by checking the content height after the WebView has finished loading and if its value is 0, it then attempts to reload the url.

```
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                if (view.getContentHeight() == 0) view.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });
```